# Ruby: What is the easiest way to remove the first element from an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say I have an array

```
[0, 132, 432, 342, 234]
```

What is the easiest way to get rid of the first element? (0)

Comment: 'shift' is pop and 'unshift' is push. In which shift takes in the number of parameters to pop

Answer (score 316, accepted):

"pop"ing the first element of an Array is called "[shift](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shift)" ("unshift"
being the operation of adding one element
in front of the array).

Comment: Note this mutates the array and returns `nil` on an empty array. See `drop` for an alternative, as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: If mutating the same object, but there is a desire to have the return be the array, then the following will achieve this: `array.tap(&:shift)`. Here is the documentation on `tap`: https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-tap

Answer (score 457):

#### Use `.drop(1)`.

This has the benefit of returning a new Array with the first element removed, as opposed to using `.shift`, which returns the removed element, not the Array with the first element removed.

*NOTE: It does not affect/mutate the original Array.*

```
a = [0,1,2,3]

a.drop(1)
# => [1, 2, 3] 

a
# => [0,1,2,3]
```

And, additionally, you can drop more than the first element:

```
[0,1,2,3].drop(2)
=> [2, 3]

[0,1,2,3].drop(3)
=> [3]
```

Comment: Best answer since (a) evaluates to the trimmed array, and it works as expected on an empty array: `[].drop(1) => []`

Comment: Also the best answer because OP said "what's the easiest way to get rid of the first element"

Comment: This answer showcases that it is recommendable to scroll down even if the first and excepted answer has already more than 100 upvotes. Thank you.

Comment: +1 since this returns a modified array, whereas `shift` mutates the array in place and returns the shifted element (or `nil` if array was empty)

Comment: Folks, OP didn't specify whether or not they wanted the operation to mutate the original array. So this answer is no better than the accepted answer of #shift. In fact, #shift is a better match for OP's phrasing of "get rid of" IMO. A complete answer, however, would have provided both #shift and #drop and explained the difference.

Answer (score 335):

Use the `shift` method on array

```
>> x = [4,5,6]
=> [4, 5, 6]                                                            
>> x.shift 
=> 4
>> x                                                                    
=> [5, 6]
```

If you want to remove n starting elements you can use `x.shift(n)`

Comment: the explanation should be merged into the correct answer since the content is the same

Answer (score 141):

```
[0, 132, 432, 342, 234][1..]
=> [132, 432, 342, 234]
```

So unlike `shift` or `slice`, this returns a new array, keeping the original array untouched (useful for one liners).

Comment: One gotcha to watch out for: if the array is empty it returns nil: `[][1..-1] => nil` and not `[]`.

Comment: Isn't `[1,2,3].shift` a one-liner?

Comment: @thekingoftruth: yes, but it evaluates to the element you threw away, not the rest of the array, so it takes another line.

Comment: I like this answer because it's a one line _expression_ that you can use anywhere.  To avoid the [] vs nil problem, you can do `arry[1..-1] || []`.  But arry.drop(1) is even better.

Comment: I'm going with this cuz it's simple, how would you get the "array minus what got shifted out", I can't see how that'd work... It's the main answer but it doesn't seem to answer the question since this next step isn't obvious to a newbie!

Comment: I like this approach since it's one-liner and does not modify original array

Answer (score 116):

This is pretty neat:

```
head, *tail = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#==> head = 1, tail = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As written in the comments, there's an advantage of not mutating the original list.

Comment: very clever, and works perfectly.  Once you do this, you'll have both variables "head" and "tail" at your disposal.

Comment: This reminds me a lot of lisp. `(let ((head (car mylist)) (tail (cdr mylist)) ...)`

Comment: @hurikhan77 Nice! I've been meaning to give it a try. Knowing that Darcs is written in Haskell helps pique my interest.

Comment: This version also has the advantage of not mutating the original list

Comment: useful when extracting info without an aditional step 
`header, *properties = CSV.read(file_path,encoding: 'ISO-8859-1')`

Answer (score 18):

or `a.delete_at 0`

Answer (score 18):

Use shift method

```
array.shift(n) => Remove first n elements from array 
array.shift(1) => Remove first element
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shift

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
a.slice!(0)
```

[slice!](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002206) generalizes to any index or range.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Array.delete_at(0) method which will delete first element.

```
 x = [2,3,4,11,0]
 x.delete_at(0) unless x.empty? # [3,4,11,0]
```

Comment: I don't think `unless x.empty?` is necessary. It simply returns `nil` if the index is out of range.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
arr - [arr[0]]
```

or

```
arr - [arr.shift]
```

or simply

```
arr.shift(1)
```

Comment: arr - [arr[0]] this would fail for a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4], because 1 is repeated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
 a.delete(a[0])   
 a.delete_at 0
```

Both can work