# Ruby on Rails MultiSelect box, first value is coming blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, multi-select

I have a multi select box in my file.

```
<%= c.select(:city, [['Indore', 'Indore'],
                                  ['Delhi', 'Delhi'],
                                  ['Kolkata', 'Kolkata'],
                                  ['Hydrabad', 'Hydrabad'],
                                  ['Jabalput', 'Jabalput']
                                 ],{ },
                                   { :multiple => true }
                                 ) %>
```

when i select "Hydrabad" and "Jabalpur" cities and submit the form then params is coming like

```
(rdb:3359) p params
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SsuXi8K205lHGsKJgkqGpps09gCbehJoO/R8vXGWx+g=", "city"=>{"city"=>["", "Hydrabad", "Jabalput"
]}, "commit"=>"Save City", "controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"addCity"}
```

> So in the city "city"=>{"city"=>["", "Hydrabad", "Jabalput"
>       ]}

, first value is coming blank i.e coming before "Hydrabad"

Please clear this behavior? I don't want that blank value as first position.

Comment: Please refer this link: [Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929230/why-is-the-first-element-always-blank-in-my-rails-multi-select-using-an-embedde

It will help you.

Comment: Please refer this link: [Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929230/why-is-the-first-element-always-blank-in-my-rails-multi-select-using-an-embedde

It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following link might help you.  You want to remove the first element from the list (the unnecessary extra one) when you submit the form.

[Ruby: What is the easiest way to remove the first element from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615700/ruby-what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-the-first-element-from-an-array)

You want to use the `shift` function, more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved, actually i used

> city.delete_if{|x| x.empty?

after executing above code the city array is coming

> {"city"=>["Hydrabad", "Jabalput" ]}

Please let me know if there is any other better solution?